# How can I exclude a sheet in an array, and sort with a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that was posted here a while back that I recently started using for a Google spreadsheet after tweaking it a bit. However there are two things I have not been able to accomplish: the first thing is to exclude the master sheet from the arrange (this should be done so when I re-run the code I don't get duplicates). This is what I tried

```
var repArray  = new Array();
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var allSheets = ss.getSheets().not("Master";
```

It doesn't work.

Second, in order to sort the master sheet by the first column but starting at the second row (to prevent the header row from getting sorted) I tried this

```
mSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 12).sort(2);
```

No luck either.

Here is the whole code:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var menuEntries = [ {name: "Consolidar Informacion", functionName: "updateMaster"}];
 ss.addMenu("Mejoras", menuEntries);
}
function updateMaster() {

 var repArray  = new Array();
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allSheets = ss.getSheets().not("Master");
 // build array of all sheets
 for (i in allSheets) {                              

      {repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());}
 }

 // store all sheets in array
 var sheetArray = [];   
 // loop through all rep sheets                             
 for (var j in repArray) {       
   // get each sheet                    
   var tempSheet  = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]);  
       // get sheet data
   var dataRange  = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   // remove the first header row
   dataRange.splice(parseInt(0), 1);                 
       // append sheet data to array
   var sheetArray = sheetArray.concat(dataRange);    
 }

 // Time to update the master sheet
 var mSheet    = ss.getSheetByName("Master");        
 // save top header row
 var headerRow = mSheet.getRange(1,1,1,12).getValues(); 
 // clear the whole sheet
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});                 
 // put back the header row 
 mSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(headerRow);  
 // write to the Master sheet via the array 
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);
  // force spreadsheet updates
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();                   
 // pause (1,000 milliseconds = 1 second)          
 Utilities.sleep("200");                             
  // Sorts the sheet by the first column, ascending
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 12).sort(2);
 // delete empty rows at bottom
 var last = mSheet.getLastRow();                     
 var max  = mSheet.getMaxRows();
 if (last !== max) {mSheet.deleteRows(last+1,max-last);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions in here:

**You need the index of the master sheet.**  Say it's the first sheet:

```
var allSheets = ss.getSheets(); //get all the sheet
var indexOfMaster = 0; //or whichever the index is
var sheetsExceptMaster = allSheets.splice(indexOfMaster,1); //splice out 1 item at this index, which would be the master sheet
```

**The other Q is about sorting a range.**  This line doesn't reflect what you're trying to do:

```
mSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 12).sort(2);
```

It says that you want a range that is one row deep and 12 columns wide, and then to sort the second column of that range. Remember:

```
//getRange(x, y, number of rows, number of columns).sort(by which column);
```

So what you may want is this, according to your explanation:

```
mSheet.getRange(2, 1, mSheet.getLastRow, mSheet.getLastColumn).sort(1);
```

Comment: Hi @zbnrg I updated the code with the provided suggestions, I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null."  But I do not know which instance is the null one, i'm guessing  `mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);`

might ve the problem but I'm not to sure

Comment: Hi just realized that one of my coworkers changed the Sheet name thats why I was getting the Null error how ever now I get a Service error: Spreadsheets Run the debbuger got Service error: Spreadsheets (line 62,

which reads

`var last = mSheet.getLastRow(); `

Comment: hm, what if you try `var last = mSheet.getDataRange.getLastRow();`

Answer (score 0):

So after reading a bit it was not the code that was not working its more like an ongoing issue with Google Script, somehow now the script is working, additionally I couldn't quite make the `splice` to work so what I did is to first swipe the info from Master Senpai Sheet and then just get the whole arrange as it was, my final working code reads as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var menuEntries = [ {name: "Consolidar Informacion", functionName: "updateMaster"}];
 ss.addMenu("Mejoras", menuEntries);
}
function updateMaster() {

 var repArray  = new Array();
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
 var mSheet    = ss.getSheetByName("Master Senpai")
mSheet.getRange(2, 1, mSheet.getLastRow(), mSheet.getLastColumn()).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  // build array of all sheets
 for (i in allSheets) {                              

      {repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());}
 }

 // store all sheets in array
 var sheetArray = [];   
 // loop through all rep sheets                             
 for (var j in repArray) {       
   // get each sheet                    
   var tempSheet  = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]);  
       // get sheet data
   var dataRange  = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   // remove the first header row
   dataRange.splice(parseInt(0), 1);                 
       // append sheet data to array
   var sheetArray = sheetArray.concat(dataRange);    
 }

 // Time to update the master sheet
 var mSheet    = ss.getSheetByName("Master Senpai");        
 // save top header row
 var headerRow = mSheet.getRange(1,1,1,12).getValues(); 
 // clear the whole sheet
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, mSheet.getLastRow(), mSheet.getLastColumn()).clear({contentsOnly: true});                 
 // put back the header row 
 mSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(headerRow);  
 // write to the Master sheet via the array 
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);
  // force spreadsheet updates
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();                   
 // pause (1,000 milliseconds = 1 second)          
 Utilities.sleep("200");                             
  // Sorts the sheet by the first column, ascending
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, mSheet.getLastRow(), mSheet.getLastColumn()).sort(1);
  // Resize the columns
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(2);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(3);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(4);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(5);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(6);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(7);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(8);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(9);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(10);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(11);
 mSheet.autoResizeColumn(12); 
 // delete empty rows at bottom
 var last = mSheet.getLastRow();                     
 var max  = mSheet.getMaxRows();
 if (last !== max) {mSheet.deleteRows(last+1,max-last);}
}
```

Many thanks.